# NaN JavaScript Result

Tags: javascript, floating-point, nan, milliseconds

I am getting a NaN result. Clearly something is not right. But I cannot figure is out what is wrong in the calculations. Heres the code:

```
var totalTime = video.duration;
var milliToHours = function (value) {
  return value / 60 / 60;
}
milliToHours (totalTime);
// howerver it returns NaN in console
```

Comment: Did you check that `video.duration` is giving an actual value?

Comment: Yes, it gives a floating point value I get 39856.6757

Comment: Maybe you are calling it too soon? ie before the video has fully loaded. Might need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just found I should use a onloadedmetadata event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`video.duration` must be undefined at function execution.  Add a `console.log(value);` statement to your function.

```js
var totalTime;
var milliToHours = function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  return value / 60 / 60;
}
console.log(milliToHours(totalTime)); // undefined => NaN
totalTime = null;
console.log(milliToHours(totalTime)); // null => 0
totalTime = 39856.6757;
console.log(milliToHours(totalTime)); // 39856.6757 => 11.071298805555555
```

Comment: yes it is video.duration its undefined but when I use the floating point value like you did in the last line it works fine

Comment: When does `viideo.duration` have a value? Is there an event (i.e. video loaded) that is fired so that you know when you can use your `milliToHours` function? Without more details or code, there's not much more assistance that can be provided.